# How to access android resource attributes

Tags: android, android-attributes, typedarray

I want to access

**`getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,android.R.styleable.TextView)`**

 
but I am having error in `styleable`. There is no `styleable` available in `android.R` .

I will use this value in my compound view.

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {
 public CustomTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(null);
 }

 public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(attrs);
 }

 public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(attrs);
 }

 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
 public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    init(attrs);
 }

 private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
    if (attrs != null && !isInEditMode()) {
        TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
        int[] textSizeAttr = new int[] { android.R.attr.textSize };
        int indexOfAttrTextSize = 0;
        TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(typedValue.data, textSizeAttr);
        int textSize = a.getDimensionPixelSize(indexOfAttrTextSize, -1);
        a.recycle();
    }
 }
```

}

### layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="hgyanani.customcompoundview.MainActivity">

    <hgyanani.customcompoundview.CustomTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try cleaning the project and rebuild it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {

    if (attrs != null && !isInEditMode()) {
        int[] attrsArray = new int[] {
                android.R.attr.textSize, // 0
        };
       TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, attrsArray);
       int textSize = a.getDimensionPixelSize(0 /*index of attribute in attrsArray*/, View.NO_ID);
  }
}
```

**textSize** will return the value in **pixel**.

If you want the exact value of textsize in **sp** then in the constructor of your custom view (the one that takes in the AttributeSet), you can retrieve the attributes from Android's namespace as such:

```
String xmlProvidedSize = attrs.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "textSize");
```

The value of the xmlProvidedSize will be something like this "16.0sp" and maybe with little bit of String editing you can just extract the numbers.

Comment: Still I cannot use `int textSize=a.getDimensionPixelSize(android.R.styleable.TextView_textSize);`

My main motive is to get 'textSize' attribute value from it.

Comment: @HarishGyanani : I think it will solve your problem. :-)

Comment: I have posted more code, please check. I have tried debugging but getting -1 in textSize variable.

Comment: Do you want to get the textSize value, you have used in XML? Or you want to set it at runtime?

Comment: as you can see in my layout file, I have used `android:textSize="16sp"`.

Comment: Ok. So you want to get this value (android:textSize="16sp) in your init method?

Comment: I am using xhdpi device so it should come 32 (32px) for that. For the same work, If I use custom attribute, I get 32 value.